# Zulu time format

Tags: shell-script, bash-scripting

I've a script which generates Zulu time zone. How do I change the format in shell /bash script like this ?

20140730000255 -> 2014-07-30

Thank you in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

LongDateTime=$1;

if ["$LongDateTime" = ""]
then
    LongDateTime=20140730000255;
fi

Year=${LongDateTime:0:4}
Month=${LongDateTime:4:2}
Day=${LongDateTime:6:2}

echo $LongDateTime

echo $Year
echo $Month
echo $Day

YMD="$Year-$Month-$Day"

echo $YMD
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very Much nurchi for quick and accurate reply. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. I don't know if you know any bash scripting. Basically, this takes the first argument in your long datetime format and extracts year, month, and day from it. Then it puts them together into a `$YMD` variable containing the date in the form you want. Feel free to change anything, but read up on bash string manipulation and bash comparison (in the `if` statement above, note that the `=` sign is surrounded by spaces on each side, this is required).